# BlackBerry virtual keyboard with customized 'enter' key

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-torch

I am using a BlackBerry Torch 9800.

The virtual keyboard appears when the focus is on my EditField, but I want to display a <kbd>go</kbd> button instead of the <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

below is my code and I have also attached image highlighting where I want to put my custom button.

```
EditField editBorder = new EditField("", "", 11, EditField.NO_NEWLINE
                | EditField.FILTER_REAL_NUMERIC) {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                fontColor("1a5ec9");
                g.getColor();
                g.setColor(ColoredFont);
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your post? I don't know what your actual question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to change the virtual keyboard look and feel.

Extend [PopupScreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/PopupScreen.html) class to implement your own virtual keyboard.